# Pandas dataframe getting average of two categories and placing in to existing column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dateframe df which is indexed by date (many same dates). I also have a column named name which has company names for each date, rating (A to Z) and category (health, utilities) etc and finally a column called price.

Price consists of many blank values with some populated values I want to fill the blanks with the average price of the other prices which are in the column price for the companies with the same rating and same category of the one which needs to be filled.

Comment: you should really provide example data, it's hard to reason about your problem otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dt['adjPrice'] = dt.groupby(['rating', 'category']).price.apply(lambda s: s.fillna(s.mean()))
```